# how to emulate "${@:2}" in /bin/dash

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix

In `bash`, this syntax can be used to get list of command line arguments, starting from `$2`:

```
echo "${@:2}"
```

This syntax does not seem to work in `sh` (`/bin/dash`).

What would be the best way to emulate this in sh ?

Comment: BTW, note that `echo "$@"` is itself buggy, insofar as `echo` doesn't distinguish between being passed `echo 'hello world' 'goodbye world'` and `echo 'hello' 'world' 'goodbye' 'world'`; in cases where the details matter, use `printf '%s\n' "$@"` (POSIX-compliant, but still ambiguous if arguments contain literal newlines), or `printf '%q\n' "$@"` (bash-only but unambiguous), or `printf '%s\0' "$@"` (POSIX-compliant, but output can only be read by humans with addition of a tool that prints NULs readably).

Comment: ...and the above is ignoring all the places where the POSIX `echo` specification just leaves its behavior flatly undefined. If your `"$@"` has its first argument as `-n`, `echo` may or may not print it; if it contains a two-character sequence `\t`, `echo` may or may not replace it with a tab; the standard leaves those behaviors, or their absence, undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(shift; echo "$@")
```

Using the subshell created by the parens ensures that `"$@"` in the outer scope is not modified.

---

As another approach (uglier, but avoiding the need for a subshell), you can remove the first argument, and re-add it later:

```
argOne=$1               # put $1 in $argOne
shift                   # rename $2 to $1, $3 to $2, etc
echo "$@"               # Pass the new argument list to echo
set -- "$argOne" "$@"   # Create a new argument list, restoring argOne before the rest
```

Comment: I get this error when there are not enough arguments: `shift: can't shift that many`

Comment: it seems that I need to do the shift only once ?

Comment: If you only want to skip one argument, then you only need to shift once.